# Бэкенд для мобильного приложения

Tags: java, c#, сервер, xamarin, мобильная-разработка

Появилась необходимость в написании мобильного приложения, поддерживающего чат, что подразумевает под собой частый обмен данными с сервером. В качестве бэкенда рассматривал backendless, но у него ограничение на 40 млн. API-вызовов на самом дорогом тарифном плане (подозреваю, что после каждой отправки сообщения его необходимо заносить в базу, т.е., как минимум, 1 API-вызов).

С работой с серверной частью приложения я пока на "вы", поэтому хотелось узнать, каким образом решается данная проблема: поскольку количество запросов при активном использовании приложения не укладывается в установленные лимиты, необходимо использовать какие-то другие способы работать с базой, т.е. какой существует наиболее подходящий сценарий работы в рамках данной задачи.

Само приложение планируется писать либо на Java под Андроид, либо Xamarin для кросс-платформенности.

Comment: <<поэтому хотелось узнать, каким образом решается данная проблема>> Какая именно проблема?

Comment: @Streletz дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> поскольку количество запросов при активном использовании приложения не
>   укладывается в установленные лимиты, необходимо использовать какие-то
>   другие способы работать с базой, т.е. какой существует наиболее
>   подходящий сценарий работы в рамках данной задачи.

Обычно под свой проект пишут свой backend. Если честно, впервые слышу о том, чтобы backend (особенно, серьёзного проекта) делали на "конструкторе".

> Само приложение планируется писать либо на Java под Андроид, либо
>   Xamarin для кросс-платформенности.

Это роли не играет. Back и front обмениваются данными по сети и поэтому не важно, что на чём написано. Сейчас по факту стандартом является взаимодействие посредство [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST).

Comment: То есть мне необходимо написать свой сервер, положить его на хостинг вместе с БД и обращаться к нему? Тогда я правильно понимаю, что узким местом будет являться производительность сервера? Если это "конструктор", тогда каково его предназначение, если не для каких-либо проектов?

Comment: Начнём с конца. Конструкторы нужны для того чтобы быстро сделать какой-никакой но работающий вариант ни во что не вникая. В этом секрет популярности Ucoz,Wix, etc. Но, у конструктора возможности всегда ограничены и по функционалу и по ресурсам.
Простенькую визитку на них можно сделать спокойно. Что-то серьёзное вряд-ли.

Comment: Что касается производительности сервера. Вовсе не факт, что проблема может в ней. Есть ещё вычислительная сложность алгоритмов ПО, скорость и качество соединения (особенно для mobile) и ряд других факторов.

Comment: Касаемо написания сервера. Уже давно есть ряд готовых серверов приложений. Главное чтобы было написано само приложение.

Comment: Какие готовые серверы можно посмотреть? И что они предоставляют, в частности, в чем будет их отличие от того же backendless? И как изменится процесс разработки приложения от разработки с помощью "конструктора"?

Comment: В качестве сервера (в зависимости от платформы) можно взять, например, nginx, Tomcat, IIS, Apache. Есть ещё ряд других. Характеристики и т.д. лучше см. в документации и статьях в интернете на профильных сайтах. Процесс разработки изменится кардинально, т.к. накликать мышью готовые компоненты и настройки не получится. Ничего этого там нет. Всё придётся писать руками самому.